# location.hash = window.location.hash does not work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, web-applications

I'm dynamically creating anchors with JavaScript after initial page load and my solution to redirecting to the anchor is calling:

```
location.hash = window.location.hash;
```

This works great and as intended in firefox, it jumps straight to the anchor without reloading the page. However when testing in chrome, this simply doesn't work. I've tried the typical approaches I use to get something to work in chrome such as, wrapping it in a timeout, using href instead of hash, and even using hash.substr(1) to try and get chrome to play ball.

I'm at a lost, any tips?

Comment: but `location.hash` is exactly the same thing as `window.location.hash` - can you produce a snippet of code to demonstrate what you are doing? because `location.hash = window.location.hash;` is like saying `a=a` ... it doesn't make sense

Comment: try `let save = location.hash; location.hash= ''; location.hash = save;`

Comment: Ahhh interesting, i'm using it in a callback where the anchors are created.

`someCallBackFunction() {
 for loop to create anchors;

 location.hash = window.location.hash; //Jump to anchor now that it exists. 
}`

Comment: it worked by ````setTimeout(function() {save = location.hash; location.hash=''; location.hash=save;},300);````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function() {save = location.hash; location.hash=''; location.hash=save;},300);
```

Was the accepted approach given by @Jaromanda X in the comments.